# How to hide the List Toolbar in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using react-admin 2.6.2 and trying currently to edit the layout of the List view. At first I wanted to remove action buttons completely, and I found the answer here at Stackoverflow. I thought, that using empty CardActions would be enough, but there's still empty ListToolbar taking space before my `<List>` starts. The toolbar is created by List automatically, is there any way to for example edit styles of that toolbar so I could hide it or set the height to 0px?

I guess one option is to create my custom List.js based on [this](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/List.js), but it would be best to use the original source files, so they are also updated when there are new updates to react-admin.

JS code:

```
const NoneActions = props => (
    <CardActions />
);

class DemoList extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <List
                    {...props}
                    actions={<NoneActions />}
                >
                    <Datagrid>
                        <TextField source="name" />
                        <ShowButton />
                    </Datagrid>
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the toolbar in DOM:

```
<div class="MuiToolbar-root-519 MuiToolbar-regular-521 MuiToolbar-gutters-520 ListToolbar-toolbar-293">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try: `<List actions={null} {...props}>` the empty space before the list disappears.

Comment: Unfortunately this also removes the Create button on the bottom right.